# SQL Server Join Confusion - How to Find Missing Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two SQL Server tables that I'm trying to compare for missing records in the 2nd table.

The first table is the master table that simply contains job titles (e.g. Web Developer, DBA, etc) and levels (e.g. Manager, Expert, etc.)

The 2nd table has a list of companies with their potential positions and rate. Each company should have every job title and level combination from the master table and many do not.

- `Master` table - `Title | Level`
- `Positions` table - `Employer | Title | Level | Rate`

I've tried using JOINS (all types), `NOT IN`, and `NOT EXISTS`.

I'm coming up with either no data or false positives for all.

I need to know which employers are missing what title and level combinations, so I can get them loaded.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: it would be great if you could post your query attempts.

Comment: I don't have them. I keep overwriting what I try because they're all not working.

Comment: sql fiddle with at least one non-working example will help

Comment: You need to include the table that has all the companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED** after re-reading and understanding the question...  The code sample below will output one row for "EmployerB / CFO" (the one position commented out during the INSERTs).  If you don't have an Employers table (you should, I think) then you could always just `SELECT DISTINCT Employer FROM PositionsTable` instead.

```
DECLARE @MasterTable TABLE
(
    Title varchar(100),
    Level int
)
DECLARE @PositionsTable TABLE
(
    Employer varchar(100),
    Title varchar(100),
    Level int,
    Rate int
)
DECLARE @Employers TABLE
(
    Employer varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Employers VALUES ('EmployerA')
INSERT INTO @Employers VALUES ('EmployerB')
INSERT INTO @MasterTable VALUES ('CEO', 1)
INSERT INTO @MasterTable VALUES ('CFO', 2)
INSERT INTO @MasterTable VALUES ('CTO', 2)
INSERT INTO @PositionsTable VALUES ('EmployerA', 'CEO', 1, 100)
INSERT INTO @PositionsTable VALUES ('EmployerA', 'CFO', 2, 100)
INSERT INTO @PositionsTable VALUES ('EmployerA', 'CTO', 2, 100)
INSERT INTO @PositionsTable VALUES ('EmployerB', 'CEO', 1, 100)
--INSERT INTO @PositionsTable VALUES ('EmployerB', 'CFO', 2, 100)
INSERT INTO @PositionsTable VALUES ('EmployerB', 'CTO', 2, 100)

SELECT *
FROM @Employers e
CROSS JOIN @MasterTable mt
LEFT JOIN @PositionsTable pt ON e.Employer = pt.Employer AND mt.Title = pt.Title AND mt.Level = pt.Level
WHERE pt.Employer IS NULL
```

The `CROSS JOIN` functions to get a complete list of Employers and the expected positions, and the `LEFT JOIN` then allows you to determine which ones are missing.  You can reduce the result set to just the columns you are interested in, but if you do that, make sure you select `e.Employer` and not `pt.Employer` (which will be NULL).

Comment: tried that...just comes up with no records, which i know is wrong

Comment: oh - after re-reading, I realize I misunderstood...  will revise shortly

Comment: I'm going to slap myself if this crap ends up being easy...i've been at it for a while now

Comment: Thanks Michael...giving it a shot now. Will let you know

Comment: That did it! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Check this query sample

```
create table #master(title varchar(100),level varchar(100))
create table #position(employer varchar(100),title varchar(100),level varchar(100))

insert into #master values('A','A1')
insert into #master values('B','B1')
insert into #master values('C','C1')
insert into #master values('D','D1')


insert into #position values('E1','A','A1')
insert into #position values('E2','A','A1')
insert into #position values('E3','A','A1')
insert into #position values('E4','A','A1')
insert into #position values('E5','X','X1')


select * from 
(select m.title,m.level,p.employer from #master m cross join #position p 
except
select m.title,m.level,p.employer from #master m inner join #position p 
on m.title=p.title and m.level=p.level) a
order by employer
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

```
declare @Master table (
    Title varchar(50),
    Level varchar(50)
)

declare @Positions table (
    Employer varchar(50),
    Title varchar(50),
    Level varchar(50),
    Rate varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Master (Title, Level) VALUES ('Web Developer', 'Manager')
INSERT INTO @Master (Title, Level) VALUES ('Web Developer', 'Senior')
INSERT INTO @Master (Title, Level) VALUES ('Web Developer', 'Junior')
INSERT INTO @Master (Title, Level) VALUES ('DBA', 'Manager')
INSERT INTO @Master (Title, Level) VALUES ('DBA', 'Senior')
INSERT INTO @Master (Title, Level) VALUES ('DBA', 'Junior')

INSERT INTO @Positions (Employer, Title, Level, Rate) VALUES 
('ABC Corp', 'Web Developer', 'Manager', ''),
('ABC Corp', 'Web Developer', 'Senior', ''),
('ABC Corp', 'DBA', 'Manager', ''),
('ABC Corp', 'DBA', 'Junior', ''),
('DEF Corp', 'Web Developer', 'Manager', ''),
('DEF Corp', 'Web Developer', 'Senior', ''),
('DEF Corp', 'Web Developer', 'Junior', '')

-- expect difference to return ABC missing WD-Junior, DBA-Senior, and DEF all DBA

; with cte as
(select distinct
    m.Title as master_title,
    m.Level as master_level,
    p.Employer
from
    @Master m CROSS JOIN @Positions p
    )

select 
    c.Employer,
    c.master_title,
    c.master_level,
    p.*
from cte c LEFT outer join @Positions p on p.Employer = c.Employer and p.Level = c.master_level and p.Title = c.master_title
where
    p.Employer IS NULL
order by
    c.Employer,
    c.master_title,
    c.master_level
```